# Catching a wide range of scene events using scripting

Tags: python, scripting

I have an idea for a Google Cardboard app, where I need it to display a Blender scene and update it as soon as it gets edited in Blender. Technically it should be a remote yet ultra simplified renderer.

I'm not sure where to start. I only know there is a scene update callback in Blender:
http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bpy.app.handlers.html

But I guess it's not enough as it does not provide extra information about what's changed.

Does an object have a modification timestamp? Or is there a dedicated API that can be used in my case?

Thanks